# 'é' character with Ruby i18ln translations

Tags: ruby, internationalization

I'm using i18ln in Ruby and providing translations for my views. My spanish translations require an acute e, or this `é` . This is my simplified translation in my `es.yml` file

```
es:
  headline: "Hola, tus créditos son:"
```

I am trying to make the `é` appear correctly, and as this is not HTML, I can't use those escaped characters. However I THINK I can use unicode. But it doesn't work for me.. I'm getting the unicode characters from here:[unicode resource](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/based)

I've tried all of the following with no luck:

```
\X*U+00E9\
\X**U+00E9\
\x*U+00E9\
\U+00E9\
```

I just want an `é` any help here?

[Here is a screen shot to see what's happening:](http://nimb.ws/56Tzq8)

And I realized you can pass along HTML in the `es.yml` file but that hasn't helped.

Comment: If you're saving your YAML as a UTF-8 encoded file this should work. If it's something else, like Latin1 or Windows-1252, you'll need to match that encoding when you load it in, or convert it properly.

Comment: Yeah, if that "weird d" works, the e should too....

Comment: @tadman saving as a UTF-8 encoded file..  what does that mean? My `es.yml` file is just a `yml` file.. nothing more or less.. How would I do that?

Comment: It means that whatever editor you're using needs to be able to save in UTF-8 encoding. Some programs make their encoding explicit, you can adjust it as necessary. Others assume some kind of default that might be wrong. Most code editors have a clear setting when saving files, and an option to convert if necessary.

Comment: Shoot, no that wasn't it.. @tadman everything is UTF-8.. even the HTML is being rendered correctly.. can't figure this out..

Comment: Have a look at what bytes are being emitted. If it's 195, 169 then that's UTF-8. If it's 233 that's perhaps Windows-1252.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, it ended up being the font. I was using Helvetica and it didn't have the right characters. I switched over to Roboto, which does have that character and everything is golden. Wow, lesson learned.